# Do you participate in Stack Overflow during your work hours?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation

I realize that I have a tab to Stack Overflow permanently open at work, and I check several times a day if I could answer questions, to the detriment of my work.

And you?

- Do you participate often during work hours?
- For questions relevant to your work or just to increase your reputation?
- Have you had problems with your boss, colleagues, etc? Anecdotes?

Comment: Why 2 negative votes? (I'm new on Meta)

Comment: Your question does not fit here, that's all. Nothing personal.

Answer (score 2):

I try and keep a couple of tabs open at work, but admittedly if I am head down working I probably won't check it until lunch, or a coffee break or similar.

In my mod role I do my best to check the queue at least at the start and end of day, if not more. My day job is in exactly the same industry as my main SE site, so it is very relevant to my work - especially in my community role.

Not had problems with my boss about it, and I wouldn't give any hassle to my staff for using the SE sites, unless their quality/quantity of work was low, in which case I would ask them to focus (but that would be the same no matter what the non-work distraction was)